# Selenium Webdriver.io test runner is not logging the titles of the test specs ("it should...")

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, webdriver-io, gui-testing

I am using this javascript API for Selenium called Webdriver.io. I am using the jasmine framework and running the tests with webdriverio's `$ wdio` command. I set the loggingLevel to verbose in the wdio.conf.js file but it is still not printing the titles of the specs (the "it should test ...") in the terminal. I do not want to add hard to maintain console.log()'s. How can I solve this problem.

Comment: if you show code, it'll be easy for others to answer and you'll have more chances to get an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking to see full test results with spec details when you run your tests, you can change the default reporter from 'dot' to 'spec'. In your wdio.conf.js file, look for the following line:

```
reporters: ['dot'],
```

Change it to:

```
reporters: ['spec'],
```

You will probably need to install the spec reporter:

```
npm install wdio-spec-reporter
```

There is no need to have your loglevel set to verbose, you can switch it back to silent.